# SQL get the names of the columns that are stored in a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, alias

I have an Article table with generic column names "PARAM1", "PARAM2", "PARAM3"...

The real name of these columns is stored in a different table.

```sql
SELECT
A.PARAM1, -- This is the data
N1.NOMPAR, -- This is the column name
A.PARAM2 AS N2.NOMPAR -- This does not work, but the desired output
FROM dbo.ARTICULO AS A
LEFT JOIN dbo.NOMPARAMS AS N1 ON N1.NUMPAR = 1 AND N1.TIPPAR='ART'
LEFT JOIN dbo.NOMPARAMS AS N2 ON N2.NUMPAR = 2 AND N2.TIPPAR='ART';
```

Instead of hard coding alias names for different queries from the Article table, I want to use the real live data. In addition, is there a way to not do 9 different left joins for each paramX? The DB is a mess and uses this design all over the place. Thanks

### edit:

This is what I ended up with for now:

```sql
DECLARE @DynamicTSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @DynamicTSQLStatement
= N'SELECT CODART, ' + STUFF(
                                (
                                    SELECT ',[PARAM' + RIGHT([NUMPAR] + 10, 1) + '] AS [' + [NOMPAR] + ']'
                                    FROM dbo.NOMPARAMS
                                    WHERE TIPPAR = 'ART'
                                          AND NOMPAR <> ''
                                    ORDER BY [NUMPAR]
                                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                                ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),
                                1,
                                1,
                                ''
                            ) + N'FROM dbo.ARTICULO';
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicTSQLStatement;
```

Still looking how to add joins to the query

```
SELECT C1.DESCCAR, -- This is the data
NP1.NOMPAR, -- This is the column name
C2.DESCCAR AS NP2.NOMPAR, -- This does not work, but the desired output
A.PARAM1, -- This is the data
N1.NOMPAR, -- This is the column name
A.PARAM2 AS N2.NOMPAR -- This does not work, but the desired output
FROM dbo.ARTICULO A
 LEFT JOIN dbo.CARACTERISTICAS AS C1 ON(C1.TIPCAR='A' AND C1.NUMCAR='1' AND C1.CODCAR=A.CAR1)
 LEFT JOIN dbo.CARACTERISTICAS AS C2 ON(C2.TIPCAR='A' AND C2.NUMCAR='2' AND C2.CODCAR=A.CAR2)
 LEFT JOIN dbo.NOMPARAMS AS NP1 ON(NP1.TIPPAR='ART' AND NP1.NUMPAR='1')
 LEFT JOIN dbo.NOMPARAMS AS N1 ON N1.NUMPAR=1 AND N1.TIPPAR='ART'
 LEFT JOIN dbo.NOMPARAMS AS N2 ON N2.NUMPAR=2 AND N2.TIPPAR='ART';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code/logic can be used to complete your task:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #DataSource;

CREATE TABLE #DataSource
(
    [Param01] INT
   ,[Param02] INT
   ,[Param03] INT
);

DECLARE @DataHeadings TABLE
(
    [ColumnID] INT
   ,[ColumnName] SYSNAME
);

INSERT INTO #DataSource ([Param01], [Param02], [Param03])
VALUES (1, 1, 1)
      ,(2, 2, 2)
      ,(3, 3, 3);

INSERT INTO @DataHeadings ([ColumnID], [ColumnName])
VALUES (1, 'name')
      ,(2, 'age')
      ,(3, 'login');

DECLARE @DynamicTSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX);


SET @DynamicTSQLStatement = N'SELECT ' + STUFF
                            (
                                (
                                    SELECT ',[Param' + RIGHT([ColumnID] + 100, 2) + '] AS [' + [ColumnName] + ']'
                                    FROM @DataHeadings
                                    ORDER BY [ColumnID]
                                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                                ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
                                ,1
                                ,1
                                ,''
                            )
                            + 'FROM #DataSource';

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicTSQLStatement;
```

[image]

Comment: This is a great head start, thank you!
I was able to make it work with very little modifications, but I'm still trying to figure how to combine your solution with other generic columns that take their name from yet another table called "NOMCARACS".

    SELECT
    C1.DESCCAR, -- This is the data
    NP1.NOMPAR -- This is the column name
    FROM dbo.ARTICULO A
    LEFT JOIN dbo.CARACTERISTICAS AS C1 ON (C1.TIPCAR='A' AND C1.NUMCAR='1' AND C1.CODCAR=A.CAR1)
 LEFT JOIN dbo.NOMPARAMS AS NP1 ON (NP1.TIPPAR = 'ART' AND NP1.NUMPAR ='1');

Comment: @Joe could you past these details in other question. It seems to messy for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using some dynamic SQL like the following:

```
DECLARE @NOMPAR1 sysname, @NOMPAR2 sysname
SELECT
    @NOMPAR1 = CASE WHEN NUMPAR = 1 THEN NOMPAR ELSE @NOMPAR1 END,
    @NOMPAR2 = CASE WHEN NUMPAR = 2 THEN NOMPAR ELSE @NOMPAR2 END
FROM
    NOMPARAMS
WHERE TIPPAR = 'ART'


DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)
SET @sql = N'
SELECT 
    A.PARAM1 AS ' + QUOTENAME(@NOMPAR1) + N',
    A.PARAM2 AS ' + QUOTENAME(@NOMPAR2) + N'
FROM 
    ARTICULO A'
PRINT @sql

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

But it is so ugly and developer unfriendly that I would prefer to hard-code column aliases.

A better alternative would be to rely on the client application to deal with column names.